# CSS background image

Tags: css, html

I have

```
.green {
background-image:('http://i42.tinypic.com/xzup2.jpg')
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:430px;
width:100%;
}
.yellow {
background-image: url('/images/yellowlight.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:430px;
width:100%;
}
```

in my css.

`.yellow` works fine, but `.green`. does not work.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the "url" bit.

`background-image:('http://i42.tinypic.com/xzup2.jpg')`

should be:

`background-image: url('http://i42.tinypic.com/xzup2.jpg');`